# how can i solve below symfony dependency error

Tags: symfony, dependencies, hwioauthbundle

```
  The service "hwi_oauth.security.oauth_utils" has a dependency on a non-existent service "hwi_oauth.resource_ownerma
  p.main".
```

This is the error i got after executing the below command. and now this error have been displayed for every single command via prompt

```
composer require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/guzzle6-adapter php-http/httplug-bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure the bundle as described in the documentation? 
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-configuring_the_security_layer.md#b-configure-the-oauth-firewall

You probably need to add the firewall configuration:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            anonymous: ~
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                    google:             "/login/check-google"
                    my_custom_provider: "/login/check-custom"
                    my_github:          "/login/check-github"
                login_path:        /login
                use_forward:       false
                failure_path:      /login

                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```